# How does JQuery works if the JQuery IIFE is not being executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `jquery-3.3.1.js` file contains the following code:

```
( function( global, factory ) {
...
} );
```

Inside this IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) there is something like this (to allow for the use of the `JQuery` and `$` variables to call the JQuery function):

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

But this IIFE is not being executed at all! I mean shouldn't it be like this:

```
( function( global, factory ) {
...
} )();
```

Comment: *"Inside this IIFE..."* If it's not invoked, it's not an IIFE. It's just a discarded function. What comes before it?

Comment: ...looking at their code, there is a `(...)` after it. You just need to look more closely. It doesn't come at the bottom of the file, but rather under this code comment: `// Pass this if window is not defined yet`

Comment: The whole purpose of that part of the IIFE is to bring those global parameters within its lexical scope, thereby making them local to IIFE. So those globals can be whatever is available to it and in this case being jQuery, $ is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From unminified source at the CDN: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

That IIFE ***is*** being executed:

```
( function( global, factory ) {

    // ...

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
  // ...
} );
```

Extracting those args makes it much clearer:

```
const arg1 = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this;
const arg2 = function(window, noGlobal ) {
   // ...
};

( function( global, factory ) {

   // ...

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
} )( arg1, arg2 );
```

And, since that `global` argument when inside the function will most probably be `window`, it can add anything to it.